# Permanently STOP wpa_supplicant on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wpa-supplicant

I just started an AWS Ubuntu 18.04 instance using their default image. I was surprised to see this process running:

```
$ ps auxww | grep wpa
root       792  0.0  0.2  45232  5380 ?        Ss   15:43   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
```

I believe this is to do with WIFI... well obviously AWS does not have WIFI on their instances, so how do I stop this useless process from starting on reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant 
sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant
```

Answer (score 1):

[Organic Marble's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1224749/132098) (at the time of this writing) didn't work for my system (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Raspberry Pi): after rebooting, the *systemd* journal (`journalctl -f`) was polluted with new `wpa_supplicant ...` log entries every couple of seconds again.

[I also tried masking the service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69699980/923560), but this also didn't work for me.

The only thing that helped was uninstalling the [`wpasupplicant` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/wpasupplicant):

```
sudo apt remove wpasupplicant
```

After a reboot, finally `wpa_supplicant ...` *systemd* log entries don't show up anymore.